# Sitecore - Is it possible for items with same template to have different fields?

Tags: content-management-system, sitecore

I want to add a field to an item and other items who are using the same template should not get that field.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible for 2 items which use the same template.

What you can do is:

1. Create a new template and set your original template as Base Template for the new one
2. Add the extra field to the new template
3. Use the new template for your chosen item.

Comment: For example see this blog https://www.geekhive.com/buzz/post/2015/02/how-to-extend-templates-in-sitecore-cms/